# Is possible to disable HTML code highlighting in WebStorm IDE?

Tags: webstorm

It is being grey-highlighted by default.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the background color for tags in *Preferences | Editor | Colors and Fonts | Language defaults - Markup - Tag*. Or if you want to change that color for HTML tags only, you do that in You can change the background color for tags in *Preferences | Editor | Colors and Fonts | HTML - Tag*.